# JQuery inside js function

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I am using the jquery autocomplete ui,trying to make it automatically open the menu when the user clicks in the text box.
When i use `$("#selector").autocomplete( "search" , "" );` outside a function it works as intended (of course this works only one time per refresh) but when i try it inside a function it does nothing and i dont know why.

EDIT: I am also working with flask-admin who uses jinja.

```
{% extends 'admin/model/list.html' %}
{% import 'admin/model/layout.html' as model_layout with context %}

{% if search_supported %}
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="selector" onfocus="func()" />

<script>
$("#selector").autocomplete({
  source: ['test',"test2"],
  minLength: 0,
  autoFocus: true,
});

$("#selector").autocomplete( "search" , "" ); //this works

function func(){
 $("#selector").autocomplete( "search" , "" ); //this doesnt
}
</script>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/mtnkd8jy/2/

Comment: Are there any errors in the JavaScript console?

Comment: Is the function definition inside `$(document).ready()`? Inline JavaScript is executed in the global scope, so it won't be able to access nested functions.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I recommend making sure the code in your question follows common indentation practices.  I think you'll find that the code is easier for other users to understand and is more likely to generate helpful replies. :)

Comment: I have no errors on the Browser Console, is that different from the JavaScript one? i don't know how to access it
(your fiddle works for me too)

Comment: its not inside `$(document).ready()`

Answer (score 0):

I added an event listener to click event you could also change it to focus event, that will register the required action to your input...
here is a working snippet handles also the css, tested in chrome, edge, and firefox...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="selector" onfocus="func()" />
    <script>
$(document).ready(()=>{
    document.getElementById('selector').addEventListener('click', func)//hook the function the click event.
    $('#selector').val('')//to make sure the input is empty on page reload...
})
$("#selector").autocomplete({
  source: ['test', "test2"],
  minLength: 0,
  autoFocus: true,
});

function func() {
    $("#selector").autocomplete("search", "")

}

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I had to edit my answer because I got exactly what you mean after posting it the first time,

Comment: That works when its alone but when i try to use the pertinent code it in my .html it doesn't work. I'm also working with flask-admin and the code is in between Jinja blocks could that be the problem? ({% if search_supported %} code {% endif %})

Comment: I believe you need to post a better piece of code description then, so others could be able to produce the code in a better way and be able to help you...

Comment: Yes, i didn't think flask played a role in the error. I have updated the code

Comment: Try to split your codes, keep your JavaScript code separated in  a js file then refer it in your html

Answer (score 0):

I would try this. You will need to make sure your script is in the `<head>` or at the end of `<body>` and properly wrapped with `<script></script>`.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#selector").autocomplete({
    source: ['test', "test2"],
    minLength: 0,
    autoFocus: true,
  }).focus(function(e) {
    $(this).autocomplete("search", "");
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input type="text" id="selector" />
</div>
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me, the script is properly wrapped in <script></script> tags but i am using flask-admin so i don't really have <head> or <body> to work with. I will edit the code

Comment: @N1r0 it seems you're using a conditional statement. When you review the Source code for the page (the resulting HTML), does it contain your JavaScript code? It's possible it's not being rendered by Flask.

Comment: Yes it contains the js code and the first part of the autocomplete works, but the problem is if i try to run a function with a JQuery line inside of it. I tried putting other stuff without JQuery in the function for testing, like changing colors of the bar or changing the value and that does works.

Comment: @N1r0 so you see any console errors? This would suggests the jQuery Library is not loading.